# How to pin Application icon to the metro start screen in windows 8 programmatically?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-installer, windows-8.1, startmenu

How can I pin application icon to metro start screen in win8 programmatically(c#)? I know how to do it manually. I also know that it will be added automatically once I launch that application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not intended to be done by programs; it is intended to be controlled by the user. That said, in Windows 8 the tiles and shortcuts for all newly installed apps and desktop apps were pinned to start and there was an official way added to prevent this from happening on a shortcut-by-shortcut basis. In Windows 8.1 new tiles and shortcuts are not pinned, but the official options still only prevent pinning.